# transferring developments in bundle between environments

Tags: bundle, netsuite

1. If we develop functionality in Sandbox (or Dev) and deploy using bundles to Production, once we lose the origin environment (for example - sbox refreshed), how does it affect the target org? (Production in this case) How does it affect future developments?
2. What is the best practice for maintaining and deploying code? Should we work in only Sandboxes? Use development org as well even though they cannot be refreshed? What should we do after sandbox refreshes?

Comment: Something to keep in mind:  Bundling from a development org to either a sandbox or a production account will put all of your code into the SuiteBundles -> Bundle ID folder in the target account.  Bundling from a sandbox into it's related production account will maintain the folder structure that you had in the sandbox environment.